# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'prefixfile' before initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

*i searched stackoverflow before asking this, none really solved my issue*

I'm writing a discord bot and I'm writing a way to have custom prefixes. So far, I have this for handling situations where the prefix for a guild isn't in the json file.

```js
const prefixfile = require('./prefixes.json');
function writePrefix(guildid) {
    const currentprefixes = prefixfile;
    
    currentprefixes[guildid] = "!";
    fs.writeFile('./prefixes.json', JSON.stringify(currentprefixes), output => {
        console.log(output);
    });
    delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./prefixes.json`)];
    const prefixfile = require('./prefixes.json');
}
```

I get the error `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'prefixfile' before initialization`

EDIT: I've fixed that issue and got another:

```js
fs.writeFile('./prefixes.json', JSON.stringify(currentprefixes), output => {
        console.log(output);
});
```

that doesn't write anything to ./prefixes.json, even though currentprefixes has data that should be written.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Even though a variable named `prefixfile` is declared outside your function, the first line of your function references the variable declared locally with same name - even though it is still not declared at that point. This happens because all the variables of your program are added to their respective lexical scopes at compile time - before any code has a chance to run.

However, since the local variable is declared with `const`, trying to access it before it has actually been declared will cause the `ReferenceError` that you see.

See the TDZ (Temporal Dead Zone) notes for further information on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#temporal_dead_zone_tdz

Comment: I've fixed that issue. I have a different issue now where fs.writeFile will just write nothing, when it should write currentprefix. currentprefix has data (confirmed with an eval command i made for debugging, also console.log)

Answer (score 0):

like IAmDranged said, the variable prefixfile was not declared in the function. I fixed that by not using a function and moving it all inside my if statement. My other issue was that fs.writeFile() didn't write anything - I fixed by using fs.writeFileSync().